# Adding Android to the Xamarin Forms Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-forms-4

I have a project that was created a while ago in Xamarin Forms, and it contained the iOS project. My task was to do the Android implementation. I created the Android project inside the main project, added the references, all the configurations were done, the project has no errors, it's compiling and displaying a blank page in the emulator as if nothing existed.
I need to know if there is any way to replicate the folders I need, if this should be created automatically or if I can replicate manually.

I changed Java versions to check compatibility, but as it is compiling and displaying I believe this is not the error.

Comment: create a new XF project with Android selected, and compare the files in the Android project with what you created.  Be sure to compare the `MainActivity` is both projects

Comment: 1) Also open projects' `.csproj` files in a text editor. Perhaps something in a new XF project's Android .csproj needs to be added to your real project. 2) As a test, comment out any custom code you run during startup, and don't go to your actual page: see if you can get a trivial page, with a single "Hello World" label, to display. Or to put it another way: can you do what the default XF project template does for Android, and see that within your project?

Comment: When you create a new xamarin.form project, it will contain a android project automatically. Did you have two mainactivity?